# Unity3D beginner RestartButton. Sharing information between scenes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, menu, uibutton

I want a restart menu that works for all my levels, as I load level 1 there is this script setting an integer to 1 on an empty game object.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SetRestart : MonoBehaviour {

    public int Setrestart = 1;

    void awake ()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad (this);
    }
   }
```

When you fail the level you get to the next scene called: LostMenu. You have the option to restart that level you were playing or quit. So here I made a button to restart and attached this script to it:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RestartButton : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public int Setrestart;

    void Start()
    {
        if (Setrestart == 1) {
            Application.LoadLevel("Main");
        }
    }
 }
```

(Plan is to make 50 levels and also 50 if statements, this is just the first one for the first level called "Main", every level will have its own number).
The problem is that nothing happens when I click on the button (Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/9tf4dd) and that when I load the LostMenu screen nothing happens to the int and it stays at 0 in the inspector while in the level scene called: "Main" I said to it to give it 'int = 1.' The number 1 stays in the "Main" scene and doesn't go to the menu scene.

Level 1 is scene: "Main".

The menu to restart when you lose is scene: "LostMenu".

Am I clear? Sorry for my bad English and thank you in advance.

Comment: I summarise some of the possible ways to do that in an article https://unitygem.wordpress.com/leaderboard-and-saving-data/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a static 'Globals' class to persist data between scenes in Unity.

You could use something like this to store the name of the last level that you played.

```
public static class Globals
{
    public static string LastLevel {get; set;}
}
```

Then you could just write to this string at the start of your level and read it in your restart button handler.

Comment: Globals are dirty, useful, but kind of frowned upon.  For one's first game, it should be OK, just keep in mind that this tends to cause any kind of public information to bloat the globals file rather than using proper inter-instance references.

Comment: I very much disagree. There is nothing dirty about globals. And globals may be frowned upon by the same people that over complicate and over engineer things just so they can be 'more clever'.

That being said. You should always use appropriate architecture paradigms for whatever you are doing. In this case, the simple strait forward approach is by far the best.

Comment: Really, *it depends.*  Hence the caution about *how* they end up being bad, rather than "don't use Globals."

Answer (score 0):

In order for `RestartButton` to know about the `Setrestart` value stored in `SetRestart` you need to have a *reference* to the GO with the `SetRestart` component.  Right now `RestartButton` is checking its *own* `Setrestart` value, which defaults to 0.  This is why it doesn't work.

Instead you need this:

```
public class RestartButton : MonoBehaviour 
{
    GameObject persistentObject;

    void Start()
    {
        persistentObject = GameObject.Find("NameOfGameObject");
        int shouldReset = (persistentObject.GetComponent<SetRestart>() as SetRestart).Setrestart;
        if (shouldReset == 1) {
            Application.LoadLevel("Main");
        }
    }
 }
```

GameObject.Find isn't great, performance wise, but for a once-off lookup, it's fine.  There are also other ways of getting the reference, but in the case of objects that persist across scene changes, this is the only way (note that I'm saving the GameObject reference to a field, while not neccessary *here* it is good practice so you aren't GO.Find()ing all the time).

Comment: Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Error says it's on the line saying: int shouldReset = (persistentObject.GetComponent<SetRestart>() as SetRestart).Setrestart;

Comment: That bit where I have `"NameOfGameObject"`?  You need to change that to match your setup.